# Have loaded a CSV layer with a QGIS plugin (so far so good) but cannot add a field to it in the same plugin

Tags: qgis, python

I have created my first ever plugin in QGIS 2.10.1 Pisa, and the layer loads fine, but after two days of trying, I cannot get the plugin to also add a field.  The following code in the "def run(self):" section doesn't cause any error, but also does not add the field.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here, please?

```
filename = self.dlg.lineEdit.text()
uri="file:///"+filename+"?"+"delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s"%("\t", "Set Grid Easting", "Set Grid Northing")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "SpreadTests", "delimitedtext")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)

vpr = vlayer.dataProvider()
vpr.addAttributes([QgsField("Testing", QVariant.Double)])
vlayer.updateFields()
```

Comment: Do delimited text data providers support attribute additions? I think you can check by printing capabilities : "vlayer.dataProvider().capabilitiesString()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV layers are note editable (due to OGR driver limitations). You can check the source of the [Editable GeoCSV plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/editablegeocsv/) to see what they are doing to work around this.

Comment: Thanks for your help with that, Jono and Underdark - I guess I may look at using python to edit the file before import, or would another workaround possibly be to save it as a shapefile and edit that?